# Calculating the average value of a column and placing that answer two cells below the last value in that column

Tags: excel, vba

I want to calculate the Average of column Q and place the answer 2 cells below the last value in column Q. The code I'm using performs the calculation and gives me the average of the values between Q2 and the end of column Q if I insert a msgbox but I can't get it to put the answer into the correct cell.

```
Sub AverageRates()

With ActiveSheet
'Determine last row
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim cellRange As Range

Dim myAvg As Double
lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row


'Average rate calculation
myAvg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("Q1:Q" & lastRow))
Range("Q2:Q" & lastRow).Value = myAvg

'place the calculated average value 2 cells below the last cell in column Q

Set cellRange = Range("Q" & Lastrow").offset(2,0).select



End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close ... try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub AverageRates()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim myAvg As Double

    With ActiveSheet
         lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row
        myAvg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("Q1:Q" & lastRow))
        Range("Q" & lastRow).Offset(2, 0).Value = myAvg
    End With

End Sub
```

For a multi-column answer, assuming the columns are not equal in length (if so, then you could use an approach like @BigBen suggests), then you could do something like:

```
Sub AverageRates2()

    Dim mySheet As Worksheet
    Dim myColumn As Range
    Dim myDataSet As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim myAvg As Double

    Set mySheet = ActiveSheet
    For Each myColumn In mySheet.Range("J:Q").Columns
        lastRow = mySheet.Cells(mySheet.Rows.Count, myColumn.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        myAvg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(myColumn.Rows(1).Resize(lastRow, 1))
        myColumn.Rows(lastRow).Offset(2, 0).Value = myAvg
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you advise on what amendments I might make to the above if I wanted the averages for columns J to Q, still using Offset(2,0) for each result?

Comment: @StephenCallaghan - you could just do `.Range("J" & lastRow & ":Q" & lastRow).Offset(2).Formula = "=AVERAGE(J1:J" & lastRow & ")"`. This is assumes that columns J to Q have the same last row.